# Actionable email developer dashboard not working

Tags: adaptive-cards, office365connectors

Tried to log into the Actionable email developer dashboard but its not working
[image: Error on dashboard]

Anyone else get the error?

Wondering what to do?

Comment: Has anyone else encountered this error?

Comment: adding the url to such a question (rather than only an image) would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Same here on multiple accounts multiple tenants.  Open support case w MSFT.

Comment: Yea same sorry...seems to be broken atm

Answer (score 0):

We have opened a ticket to microsoft and they have told us that it is a temporary error. Now it seems to work!!